# the usage of 'many', 'much', 'few', and 'little' as a pronoun

Tags: pronouns, collocations, countability

As far as I know, all the words can be used as a pronoun. 'many' and 'few' occur with countable nouns, while 'much' and 'little' with uncountable nouns. There are two confusing sentences, which I saw in a grammar book.

> (1) I'm not very busy today. I haven't got **much** to do.

> (2) This is a very boring place to live. There's **little** to do.

Why both sentences don't use 'many' and 'few' instead? I think 'many' would represent 'many (things)' in the first sentence , and 'few' would represent 'few (things)' in the second sentence. Is my understanding right? Or actually there are some collocations which need 'much' and 'little' with the to-infinitive.

Comment: They are determinatives, not pronouns.

Comment: I'm not sure I've correctly understood what you meant. In some situations, e.g. in the example sentences, 'much' and 'few' as a determinative can be used alone without following nouns, can't they? @BillJ

Comment: Yes, they can, but that doesn't make them pronouns. In modern grammar, they are called 'fused head' noun phrases because the determinative and the noun are combined, or 'fused', into the single word "much" (and "little").

Comment: Thanks!!! @BillJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point. It's not short for a number of **things**; you could think of it as short for an amount of **work** or **stuff** to do. (These are mass nouns.)

- I have a lot of stuff to do.
- I have so much stuff to do.
- I have very little work to do.

Etc. For whatever reason, "I have many/few to do" is not the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that if you wanted to use "many *things* to do" or "few *things* to do" the noun is necessary; leaving it out would be incorrect. "Much to do" and "little to do" do not require the explicit noun; putting it in would also be incorrect.

The distinction (as nschneid just said, I see) is that "many" and "few" are used exclusively for **count nouns**, while "much" and "little" are used for **non-count** (or **mass**) **nouns**.